# connecting a 3rd monitor to a windows-pc

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have graphics card with dual-outputs on a PC.  I would like to setup a 3rd monitor. I have another PC which has 2 graphics card slots, which have two graphics cards and I can connect the 3rd monitor to.  However in this case, it has only one slot for 1 graphics card.

Is there any other way to connect a 3rd monitor?

Comment: You plan installing both graphic cards into the same computer I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a modern processor (starting from Sandy Bridge and up), you can connect the third monitor to the motherboard through one of its video outputs. You'll have to tinker around the BIOS to make sure that the iGPU is enabled.

If you don't, then you'll need to purchase an ATI graphics card, as they natively support 3 displays out of a single GPU (Nvidia only support 2, if I remember correctly). Of course, you'll need to check that the GPU features 3 display outputs. Also, you'll most likely need to purchase appropriate adapters for your monitors.

Comment: I already have another PC which has a motherboard with SLI, and I connected two graphics cards.  ATI have cards that have physically 3 connections on one card?  I'll check about the integrated GPU option, seems a good idea, thanks!

Comment: I've managed with the onboard graphics card, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All hope is not lost, you have a few options.

1:  Get a graphics card that supports 3 or more monitors.  Most ATI cards do and a few specialized NVidia cards will as well.

2:  Try to take advantage of the integrated graphics on your motherboard.  This may not be an option if you don't have integrated graphics but it's an easy free option if you do.

3:  Use a tool like a the Mattrox Dual Head which makes the computer think it's plugged into an ultra high resolution monitor then splits the image to two different monitors.

4:  If your computer has USB 3.0 you can buy an adapter that goes from USB 3.0 to a monitor.

5:  Install a second PCI graphics card, not a PCI-Express but a standard PCI.  I bet you have an open slot, the performance would be terrible but if your not planning on doing media on the third monitor it would probably be okay.

6:  Buy a new computer that supports 3 monitors.

I would be happy to elaborate more on any of these options if you need me to.